# How to solve the following summation problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\arctan\frac{ 1 }{ k }=\frac{\pi}{ 2 }$$
Find value of $n$ for which equation is satisfied.

Comment: Do you mean $\tan^{-1}1/n$?

Comment: You should correct this expression, that does not make sense. It is probably $\sum_{k=1}^n\tan^{-1}\frac1k$.

Comment: $\arctan$ and $\tan^{-1}$ both refer to the same function (under any sane interpretation of indices on trig functions, anyway).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

n=3.
By drawing this figure, you can easily know
[image]

Comment: And how do you know it does't hold for $n=15764538$? :)

Comment: @ᛥᛥᛥ The picture itself is already explain why it only holds for $n=3$.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey I know. That's why I put the " :) ".

Comment: (it's probably not worth fixing, but) shouldn't that be `arctan` in the picture, not `acrtan`?

Answer (score 7):

Let use write $$s_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \arctan\frac1k.$$
The sequence $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbf N}$ is increasing.
We have $s_0=0$, $s_1=\frac\pi4$ and $s_2=\frac\pi4+\arctan\frac12$.
As $\frac12<1$, $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac12\right)<\frac\pi4$ and $s_2<\frac\pi2$.
Let us compute $s_3$ using the [arctan addition formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Arctangent_addition_formula)
$$s_3=\frac\pi4+\arctan\frac12+\arctan\frac13=\frac\pi4+\arctan\frac{\frac12+\frac13}{1-\frac12\frac13}=\frac\pi4+\arctan1=\frac\pi2.$$
$n=3$ is a solution. As $s_4>s_3$, it's the only one.