# how to get the answer of the following summation

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

$$\sum\limits_{k=3}^n\arctan\frac{ 1 }{ k }=\frac{\pi}{ 4 }$$
Find value of $n$ for which equation is satisfied.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802960/how-to-solve-the-following-summation-problem

Comment: I only posted that question :p

Answer (score 2):

If the summation starts at $k=3$, I have the feeling that there no value of $n$ such that $$f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=3}^n\arctan\frac{ 1 }{ k }-\frac{\pi}{ 4 }$$could be equal to $0$.

$f(n)$ increases with $n$ and you have $$f(3)\simeq -0.463648$$ $$f(4) \simeq -0.218669$$ $$f(5) \simeq -0.021273$$ $$f(6) \simeq +0.143875$$.

If the summation would have started at $k=2$, using Fabien's suggestion, the solution would have been $n=3$.

Comment: Answer given is 47 ...

Comment: @user142634 That answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum\limits_{k=3}^5\arctan\frac{ 1 }{ k }\approx \frac{\pi}{ 4 }
$$
To prove that, use :
$$
\tan(a+b)=\frac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}
$$

Comment: The suggestion is good but the statement is untrue.

Comment: see [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arctan%281%2F3%29+%2B+arctan%281%2F4%29+%2B+arctan%281%2F5%29+-+pi%2F4) and also Claude Leibovici's answer.